# How to store PreRequestFilter information in AuthUserSession

Tags: session, authentication, caching, servicestack

I am building a web service using ServiceStack which has to support multiple vendors. The web service provides largely the same functionality to all vendors with some exceptions here and there.

In order to re-use as much functionality as possible I have come up with the following URL scheme:

```
http://localhost/brand1/templates
http://localhost/brand2/templates
```

"brand1" and "brand2" are not services but "templates" is. The Templates service's request DTO's will have a property called "Brand" like so:

```
[Route("/{Brand}/templates", "GET")]
public class GetTemplates
{
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

So in the Templates service I know which brand I am dealing with. This scheme works well.

What I cannot figure out though is this. The user of the service has to be authenticated and I cannot figure out how to handle the redirection of the service after the user has been authenticated since I have to pass along the brand information. I have created my own CustomAuthProvider class that inherits  CredentialsAuthProvider. In the TryAuthenticate method I can set the authService.GetSession().ReferrerUrl property to the correct brand if I know what it was.

The only way I have found so far to get this information is to register a PreRequestFilter. My thinking here was that since the URL (e.g. http://localhost/brand1/templates) contains the brand I can store it in my own AuthUserSession class. I can't figure out how to do this. I have a "SessionFactory" method that I pass to the AuthFeature constructor. But what should I do in there? How do I get to the brand that I've obtained in the PreRequestFilter? Is it safe to store it in a field of the AppHost? I think not because of concurrency issues. How do I tie the PreRequestFilter to the SessionFactory method?

I hope I am explaining my problem clearly enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overthinking the solution because I didn't realize that I had all the information I needed in the IServiceBase parameter of the TryAuthenticate method of the CredentialsAuthProvider class.

In the end I came to the following solution:

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, 
               string userName, string password)
    {
        var session = authService.GetSession();
        var origQuery = authService.Request.UrlReferrer.Query;          

        session.ReferrerUrl = "/error";

        var queryString = origQuery.Substring(10);  // strip "redirect="
        var decodedUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(queryString);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(decodedUrl))
        {
            var query = new Uri(decodedUrl);
            session.ReferrerUrl = query.AbsolutePath;
        }

        return DoAuthentication(userName, password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The different places where you can set the Url to redirect to during [ServiceStack Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization), in order of precedence are:

1. The `Session.ReferrerUrl` Url if it's populated
2. The **Continue** QueryString, FormData param when making the request to `/auth` (i.e Authenticate.Continue property)
3. The HTTP **Referer** HTTP Header
4. The **CallbackUrl** of the current `AuthProvider` used

Comment: Thanks for the answer mythz. I have seen this answer to another question but I am afraid I don't see how it solves my problem. I need to know where to redirect to based on the original request URL which I get in the pre-request filter. But how do I get that information into the session? Alternatively, how can I get to the original request URL in the session factory method?

Comment: @GerhardWessels this shows different ways you can change what the user is redirected to after they authenticate. In your Request Filter you can access the Users Session with `req.GetSession()` and Save it back to the ICacheClient with `req.SaveSession()`. Otherwise you can use `req.Info[]` Dictionary for anything you want to pass down throughout the same [Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations).